# Integral Domains And Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

How Can I Prove (a+b√2,+,*) is an Integral Domain where a and b belong to rational numbers?
All I know is R is an integral Domain if it is a commutative ring and has no zero divisors.

Comment: The way you prove that a specific ring is an integral domain may depend on the ring in question, but usually you take two elements $x,y$ with $xy=0$ and show that $x$ or $y$ is $0$. With that said, what are $a, b, +$ and $*$?

Comment: a and b belong to R and +,* are normal addition and multiplication operators

Comment: You need $b$ not a square of a rational here.

Comment: @P.Bendre R or $\mathbb{R}$ usually denotes the field of real numbers, whereas in the question you say $a$ and $b$ must be rational numbers. Just to be clear, is your R the real numbers or the rational numbers ?

Comment: @gandalf61 Rational Numbers.I guess this question that i am trying to solve uses old notations

Comment: You know what an integral domain is; I assume you know what a commutative ring is, and what a zero divisor is; so what is stopping you from solving the problem? How far do you get, where do you get stuck?

Comment: Show it is a subring of $\mathbf R$, with the induced operationsand observe the latter is an integral domain, and even a field. Or show directly your set is a field.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Usually i find the identity element by plotting its group table.But in this case its getting somewhat confusing.Could You Plot its Group Table So that i can get the problem

Comment: Group table? Do you not realize that the set you are asking about has infinitely many elements? How do you propose to "plot" its group table? Anyway, your set is a subset of the real numbers, right? Do you know what the identity element is in the real numbers? and is that element in your set?

Comment: The multiplication in $R$ is the usual multiplication of numbers, so the identity element is going to be $1$ which can be written as $1+0\cdot\sqrt2$, hence it is in our ring $R$.

Comment: Do you understand what we're telling you about the identity element? Are you making any progress? Is there someplace else you're getting stuck?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Hint:** You can actually prove that it's a field: find the inverse of $a+b\sqrt2$.
You also have to prove that $a^2\ne 2b^2$ unless $a=b=0$.

Comment: How can i prove its an Commutative Ring if It is supposed to be solved by traditional route?

Comment: Oh, that involves 4 letters that denote arbitrary rational numbers, and you have to use that multiplication of rational numbers is already commutative.

Comment: OP doesn't even know what the identity element is – OP is not going to be able to find an inverse. Sometimes pays to find out where the OP is, first.